# floating label drops down after entering invalid input pattern, I am using html5 pattern validation

Tags: html, css

The floating label drops down like this!!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYqGt.png

[Form without pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u10oH.png)
1. using html5 pattern
2. label drops down after entering invalid pattern

```
<div class="form-group m-b-40">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="firstName" 
name="firstName" pattern="^[a-zA-Z_. ]*$" th:field="${user.firstName}" 
required="required"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
<label for="firstName">First Name</label>
</div>




 Please refer attached image.
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Your current code does not demonstrate the problem, not even if I put it in a form with a submit button. https://jsfiddle.net/nt91mhyx/2/

Comment: I have added floating-labels class to form and i am using ample admin template. So will need css and js files to show demo. I have also attached image.

Comment: Can you confirm that without HTML5 pattern, label are properly displayed?

Comment: I guess you got it as you updated your question with a screenshot displaying expected positioned labels without patterns

Comment: yess...i have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
input {
  outline: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 2px;
  border-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0px 0 30px;
}
input:focus {
  border-color: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group m-b-40">
<label for="firstName">First Name</label><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="firstName" 
name="firstName" pattern="^[a-zA-Z_. ]*$" th:field="${user.firstName}" 
required="required" placeholder="First Name"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span><br>

<label for="firstName">Last Name</label><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="firstName" 
name="firstName" pattern="^[a-zA-Z_. ]*$" th:field="${user.firstName}" 
required="required" placeholder="Last Name"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: No, I want to use floating input, otherwise this works fine. It seems like issue is related with floating input